# Android: Installing Wikitude on Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm trying to write some apps using wikitude, and I'm having some problems running even the example.
I've put the sample ( BasicOpenARDemo ) that comes with the SDK inside eclipse and tried to run it, where I encountered the next error: "wikitude was not found on the system. Please press the ok-button to access the Android market and download wikitude."
First question- I don't understand- Why am I approached to download the utility when I have a standalone sample inside my eclipse? Doesn't the core files behind Wikitude come with the SDK or the sample itself?

The next question will be - after some googling, I've found that in order to install this "Android market" I need to follow the manual that comes in the 9th message in the next thread (the message that was written by ronni.rasmussen) -
http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-529170.html

Well, I've followed it, and now when I try to press the OK button that comes after the "wikitude was not found on the system..." message, I get redirected to the Android market, where I find Wikitude, but when I try to download it- I get a "Download was unsuccessful. Please try again" error message. How do I fix that?
One more thing that I don't understand- How come it's written in this offline Android market that the available wikitude version is for android 1.5 and no longer maintained?

As you can see- I'm quite baffled here. Hope someone could clear this up for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was with the exact same problem. The problem was that installing Wikitude from the market (following the link you provided) does not guarantee to have the system requirements supported in the virtual device, therefore it gives an error when you run the BasicOpenARDemo, if it let you install it at all.

The solution was creating an AVD with an GoogleAPI (it includes maps support, I used the level 10 API for Android 2.3.3, it didn't work for the level 8 API), adding the camera, accelerometer, compass, GPS, etc., support to the virtual device (I did this via Eclipse). Then I downloaded the .apk for Wikitude and installed it via command line (.adb).